# Is it possible to build Thread on Global.asax

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'd like to create Thread for do something in ASP.NET.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Consider rewriting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option used (at least at some point) by Mr. Atwood himself: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

I think conventional wisdom is that a custom windows service (or even a scheduled task) is better for this sort of thing than trying to shoehorn it in to your web application, specifically if it's critical that your task run every time, on schedule.

Comment: Thank you very much, That link is quite simple but It work. :)

PS. My task still run very time as long as Application a live.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really advisable.

If possible, it's generally better to run background processes in a Windows Service; that way you have significantly more control over them.

If that's not possible (and you should really try and make sure it is) then look into [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).